# A qué se debe el error sintaxis T_VARIABLE $conn

Tags: php, sql

Este es el código

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "id9005594_juanpablo7";
$password = "999999";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password); 


// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. No hay error en tu código. El error que describes ocurriría por ejemplo si omites el punto aquí: `die("Connection failed: "  $conn->connect_error);`  o si omites el punto y coma aquí: `$password = "999999"` porque se encontraría con `$conn` sin haber indicado que hay un fin de línea o una concatenación.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta así:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "id9005594_juanpablo7";
$password = "999999";


// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password); 


// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Comment: no funciona continua dando el mismo error

Comment: estes es el error  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$conn' (T_VARIABLE) in /storage/ssd4/594/9005594/public_html/conexion_db.php on line 8

Comment: Acabo de probar el codigo (modificando el servername username y password) y funciona correctamente... estas utilizando el "conexion_db.php" en un include en otro archivo? Intenta entrar a la url de "conexion_db.php" y ve si te da error desde ahi mismo

Comment: Patrick el OP presenta un código correcto y además mucho más moderno porque usa el estilo orientado a objetos. ¿Por qué le propones que involucione, implementando el estilo procedural? Yo he probado su código tal cual y el mismo funciona. El error se produciría por ejemplo si él omitiese el punto aquí: `die("Connection failed: "  $conn->connect_error);`   o por otro motivo, pero el código de la pregunta es correcto.

Comment: Yo solo le di otra opción de conexión a su base de datos, tal vez esa otra opción le funcionaba... Pero al parecer el tiene otro tipo de error